# useContext() is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

Whenever I try to use `useContext`, it always returns `undefined`. Even though I wrapped all of the elements into `provider`.

**MessageContext.jsx file:**

```
import { useState, useContext, createContext } from "react";

export const MessageContext = createContext("KITA KO SALAMA")
export const MessageUpdateContext = createContext()

export function useMessage(){
    return useContext(MessageContext)
}

export function useMessageUpdate(){
    return useContext(MessageUpdateContext)
}

export function MessageProvider({ children }){
    const [messageContent, setMessageContent] = useState()

    return (
        <MessageContext.Provider value={messageContent}>
            <MessageUpdateContext.Provider value={setMessageContent}>
                {children}
            </MessageUpdateContext.Provider>
        </MessageContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

**App.jsx file:**

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar"

    // Pages //
    import Home from "./pages/Home"
    import SignUp from "./pages/Auth/SignUp"
    import Welcome from "./pages/Auth/Welcome"
    // Pages //
    import Message from "./components/Message"

    // Other Imports //
    import { MessageProvider } from "./context/MessageContext"
    // Other Imports //

   function App() {

      return (
        <>
          <MessageProvider>
            <Navbar />
            <Message />
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="/signup" exact element={<SignUp />} /> 
              <Route path="/support" exact element={<Support />} />
              <Route path="/welcome" exact element={<Welcome />} />
            </Routes>
          </MessageProvider>
        </>
      )
   }

    export default App
```

This is the code that I use to display it, I have imported both useContext and Message context: `console.log("context value is: " + useContext(MessageContext))`.

Comment: In which component do toy try to access this context?

Comment: `const [messageContent, setMessageContent] = useState()` will create an initial value of `undefined`

Comment: John detlefs thank you so much its working now